# accessing data from database and displaying it in textbox

Tags: c#, vb.net

I am using this code for accessing data from database and displaying it in textboxes,but i am getting whole string `columns` in 1st textbox ,how do i split and display in respective textboxes,i am getting this exception `Index was outside the bounds of the array.` at this line of code `txtOption2.Text = coldata[2];`

```
public EditQuestionMaster(int qid_value)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            string columns = db.GetEditQuestions(qid_value);
            string[] coldata=columns.Split('$');

                txtQuestion.Text = coldata[0];
                txtOption1.Text = coldata[1];
                txtOption2.Text = coldata[2];
                txtOption3.Text = coldata[3];
                txtOption4.Text = coldata[4];                           

        }
```

GetEditQuestions(qid_value) Code

```
public string GetEditQuestions(int qid)
        {
            string data = "";
            try
            {
                string sql = "select QID,Question,Opt1,Opt2,Opt3,Opt4,AnsOp,Marks from Questions where QID IN(" + qid + ") ";
                cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, acccon);
                rs = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                if (rs.Read())
                {
                    data = rs[0].ToString() + "~" + rs[1].ToString() + "~" + rs[2].ToString() + "~" + rs[3].ToString() + "~" + rs[4].ToString() + "~" + rs[5].ToString() + "~" + rs[6].ToString() + "~" + rs[7].ToString() + "$";
                }
            }
            catch (Exception err)
            {

            }
            return data;
        }
```

thank you in advance for any help

Comment: please add a value of GetEditQuetion, and why you split string with $? it means that you string array contain only one element. So when you access it you get error. Please chaneg your code as string[] coldata=columns.Split('~');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You appear to split the string by `$` but you build the string up using `~` as the separator. You need to split the string by `~` to get the appropriate number of columns i.e.

```
string[] coldata = columns.Split("~")
```

Comment: Yes Now it gives me appropriate number of columns,Thank you .

Answer (score 0):

You are seeing that error because you only have 2 items in `coldata`. Try debugging and view the length of the `coldata` array to see how many items it contains.

Change your code to use this split instead:

```
string[] coldata=columns.Split('~');
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code sample you just need to change:

```
string[] coldata=columns.Split('$');
```

To

```
string[] coldata=columns.Split('~');
```

As your columns are delimited by the **~** character.